# Compression container-format with arbitrary file operations

Tags: compression, file-format

Is there mature compression format that allows arbitrary file operations for items inside like Delete/Insert/Update but not requiring full archive recreation for this.

I'm aware of [Sqlar](https://sqlite.org/sqlar/doc/trunk/README.md) based on Sqlite file format that naturally supports this since the mentioned operations is just deleting/inserting/updating records containing blobs. But it is more like experimental project created with other goals in mind and not widely adopted

UPDATE: to be more precise with what I have in mind, this is more like file system inside the archive when the files inserted might occupy a different "sectors" inside this container, depending on the scenario of previous delete and update operations. But the "chain" of the file is compressed while being added so occupies effectively less space than the original file.

Answer (score 0):

The .zip format. You may need to copy the zip file contents to do a delete, but you don't need to recreate the archive.

Update:

The .zip format can, in principle, support the deletion and addition of entries without copying the entire zip file, as well as the re-use of the space from deleted entries. The central directory at the end can be updated and cheaply rewritten. I have heard of it being done. You would have to deal with fragmentation, as with any file system. I am not aware of an open-source library that supports using a zip file as a file system. The .zip format does not support breaking an entry into sectors that could be scattered across the zip file, as file systems do. A single entry has to be contiguous in a zip file.

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer a more capable solution, allowing managing free space inside (after delete/update) and allocating new if necessary (for insert/append). More like a file system inside a file.

Comment: Added some additional info.

Comment: Thanks, Mark (also for checksum contribution although off-topic here).I have my own implementation of zip format, I will look into it. Ironically, most likely nowdays zlib is unavoidable (as the adler field coming with it) with any outcome, even mentioned sqlar compresses the blobs with it.